# To create a movable div(which is visible only after mousehovering of other div) with scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

My Script for hide and show:

```
function SetVisible(testId) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(testId);
    var parent = obj.parentNode;
    obj.style.visibility = (obj.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}

function HideContent(testId) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(testId);
    obj.style.visibility = (obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}
```

HTML body content:

```
<div style="position:relative" onmouseover="SetVisible('hideShow');" onmouseout="HideContent('hideShow');">Check your question

    <div class="hideShow" id="hideShow" name="hideShow" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; line-height: 15px; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(90, 89, 89); font-family: verdana; visibility: hidden; left: 100%; top: 10%;">
        <table><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td></tr></table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Question is that I've to write a script to show the complete contents of "hideShow" div without scrolling the page means only this div should adjust itself as according to the space available on page.
So, I don't want any scrolling of page on mousehover on "Check your question" to show the div contents, I just want to make the div self adjustable according to the available space on the page nearby "check your question".
Thanks

Comment: @ckj Did you really write a lot of your tags without the opening `<`'s like they appear in your question?

Comment: actually I removed <'s from here as my code was not properly displaying here.

Comment: Please try at your end with including <s, 
and try to display all the contents of div on mousehovering of parent div on the space available on the page(don't scroll the page).

Comment: Ok, I formatted your code for you some more, this should work better. Now, when I enter your code into jsfiddle, I get a lot of a's when I mouse over the text: http://jsfiddle.net/mJGyQ/. How would you like it to behave differently?

Comment: Actually Spiny, I am trying to show those a's on mousehover on the available space of page. If you'll minimize your browser then you'll find that these a's are visible only after scrolling of page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mJGyQ/7/ 
Now on mousehovering, all contents are not visible for that user have to scroll down, instead of scrolling by user the div should automatically set itself in the top so that all items should be visible. Is it clear now??? :)

Comment: I got the answer in JQUERY but its bit lengthy, if anyone can convert this into javascript with mionimal lines of code then please let me know.

Comment: Hey, do you mean you now have a piece of code that does exactly what you want? Could you show it to me?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html
there you'll find the way to move the div along with the scrolling, now I want to make this code simple and easier in javascript.
If you can convert this code into simpler javascript then please do.